# builtin gcc spinlock

Tags: c, linux

How can I be sure the data that is written by multiple CPU cores during a mutex lock is synchronized across all L1 caches of all cores ? I am not talking about the variable that represents the lock, I am talking about the memory locations that are involved during the lock.

This is for Linux, x86_64, and my code is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "dlog.h"

uint *dlog_line;
volatile int dlog_lock;

char *dlog_get_new_line(void) {
    uint val;

    while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&dlog_lock, 0, 1)) {
        val=*dlog_line;
        if (val==DT_DLOG_MAX_LINES) val=0;
        *dlog_line=val;
    }

    dlog_lock = 0;
}
```

Here, inside dlog_get_new_line() function, I use gcc builtin function so there shouldn't be any problem with aquiring the lock. But how can I ensure that when the lock is released, the value pointed by *dlog_line propagates into all the L1 cache of all the other CPU cores in the system?

I do not use pthreads, each process runs on different cpu core.

Comment: Why can't you use pthreads if you are on Linux? Why do you want to avoid the standard pthreads library?

Comment: because using threads will be very slow

Comment: @R.. http://upc.lbl.gov/publications/JasonDuell_MS_report_final.pdf Citation: "Support for thread-local data needed by these global (and static) variables slows down the pthreads version by as much as 2.5x for the NAS CG and 10x for ApexMap with all global references"

Comment: @Nulik: pthreads and thread-local data are very different issues.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Currently I am working on a highly concurrent signal handler solution (i.e. need to handle _many_ bursting unix signals, while my handler could be unpredictable slow), this is an example where threads are unfeasible (although starting a new thread for every signal and using mutexes to sync them could work, it would be highly sub-optimal solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're interested in is called [cache coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence). **This is done automatically by the hardware.**

So in short, you don't have to do anything if you are correctly using `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap()` (or any other locking intrinsic).

As an oversimplfied explanation, the thread will not return from the call to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap()` until all the other processors are able to see the new value or are aware that their local copy is out-of-date.

---

If you're interested in what happens underneath (in the hardware), there are various cache coherence algorithms that are used to ensure that a core doesn't read an outdated copy of data.

Here's a partial list of commonly taught protocols:

1. [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSI_protocol)
2. [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)
3. [Firefly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_protocol)

Modern hardware will typically have much more complicated algorithms for it.

Comment: @Mystical Thanks. So I guess if I add __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&dlog_lock, 1, 0) as the last line to the function, this will be probably it, right? Because I suppose MFENCE instruction goes inside the gcc builtin function?

Comment: Yes, you will need to do that. Otherwise, other threads could zero it and allow multiple threads to enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc has two other builtins that are exactly invented for the purpose you describe: `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release`. They have so-called acquire/release semantics which guarantees you that stored values of other variables are visible as you need them while you hold your spinlock. These requirements are a bit weaker than what `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` provides, so better use the tools that are tailored for the job.

They should well adapt to the capacity of different hardware. E.g on my x86_64 this puts an `mfence` instruction before the final atomic store into `dlog_lock`, but on different hardware this will be adapted to the available instruction set.